# How to disable the "/kill" command on Minecraft server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

Because everyone on our educational server won't stop using the `/kill` command, I want to make it so that they can't use this command, but are free to use the other ones. I only want to use command blocks, but if doing this on the server is better, what's the best way of doing this?

Comment: Either install a plugin, or don't let theme use commands

Comment: Is this the vanilla Minecraft server, or something like Bukkit? I can't remember if /kill is available in vanilla.

Comment: This is a vanilla Minecraft server I think. Unfortunately I'm not the one who created it, I'm only the one who is using it.

Comment: @Kimatuy I'm fairly sure that /kill isn't available in vanilla anymore, but it's been a while since I played, so they may have added it back. Anyway, you should probably just make it so that people can't use commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your on a vannila sever there isn't much you can do, exept deoping everyone.

On Bukkit/Spigot servers you can use plugins like PermissionEx or GroupManager to allow or disallow commands for groups of players. Easier is to install plugins like DisableCommands the disallow commands for everyone.

Hope it helped :)